# Get Current time Error

Tags: java, android

[image]

my Code is

```
Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
```

how can I solve this case

Comment: Your method is expecting a [`net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.DateTime`](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/doc/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/DateTime.html).  That's not what you're giving it.

Comment: @Joe C thanks for your comment so how can I fix It I want to give the current time as a parameter

Comment: If accuracy matters and you can use Java 8, I believe you should use `new Datetime(Timestamp.from(Instant.now()))` for most accurate result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` returns an instance of `java.util.Date`.

To convert it into `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.DateTime`, you might need to write something like:

```
new DateTime(new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

There may be a shorter way, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a `java.util.Date` to a `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.DateTime`:

Step 1: Convert it to a `java.sql.Timestamp`:

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Step 2: Convert it to a `net.sourceforget.jtds.jdbc.DateTime`:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(ts);
```

Comment: Note: This has not been fully tested.  Just goes by my reading of the APIs.